# Heroku deployment returning R10 boot error

Tags: r, heroku, shiny

I would like to deploy a shiny app I built on heroku using this build pack:

> http://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git#heroku-16

I have included both a run.R and init.R file as specified in the above referred to repository. I have deployed the app

However, I am getting the error in my logs and the app isn't working

```
2020-02-04T14:24:13.671364+00:00 app[web.1]:     transpose
2020-02-04T14:24:13.671366+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-02-04T14:25:09.936204+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-02-04T14:25:09.845379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-02-04T14:25:09.845483+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-02-04T14:25:09.921158+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-02-04T14:25:12.649598+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=boxing-prediction-app.herokuapp.com request_id=4d078fa4-daee-4208-b4bf-143d68471114 fwd="41.60.121.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-02-04T14:25:14.151464+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boxing-prediction-app.herokuapp.com request_id=47571ddb-94c1-4624-b301-7a5edfa50d9a fwd="41.60.121.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-02-04T14:25:35.418191+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=boxing-prediction-app.herokuapp.com request_id=72df6f1e-409f-4778-aaca-9d9ecb3f7916 fwd="41.60.121.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-02-04T14:25:35.960407+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boxing-prediction-app.herokuapp.com request_id=d420e0b8-f078-459d-aec7-313f246e561d fwd="41.60.121.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is my app.R file:

```
...
if (!Sys.info()[['sysname']] == 'Darwin')
{
  reticulate::virtualenv_create(envname = "python_environment",python="python3")
  reticularevirtualenv_install("python_environment", packages =c('pandas','catboost'))

}
reticulate::use_virtualenv("python_environment",required = TRUE)
# boxing = read.csv(file="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EmmS21/SpringboardCapstoneBoxingPredictionWebApp/master/boxingdata/visuals.csv",header=TRUE)
boxing <- readRDS('fullboxingdataset.RDS')
#reading model
p <- import("pandas")
cat_model <- p$read_pickle("catmodelsummary.pkl")
ui <- function(){
  addResourcePath("www","www")
  tagList(
    shinyUI(
      fluidPage(setBackgroundImage(src = "www/mayweather2.png"),
                headerPanel(fluidRow(
                  column(offset = 5, width=5,
                         h2("Boxing Prediction App")),
                  column(offset = 3, width = 7,
                         h5("Welcome to Emmanuel's boxing prediction app. Using this app you can get the probability of a fight ending in a given way. The model used to derive these predictions uses data extracted before the 23rd of November 2019. Feel free to send through any feedback/suggestions to emmanuelsibanda21@gmail.com. Any updates to the data will be shown here. Without further ado, let's get ready to rumble!"))
                )),
                fluidRow(column(offset = 5, width = 2,align="center",
                                titlePanel(h5(selectInput("dropdown","Select Boxer Weights",choices=unique(boxing$division)))))),
                fluidRow(column(offset = 3, width=3,
                                wellPanel(
                                  fluidRow(
                                    uiOutput("Names"),
                                    uiOutput("boxerA")))),
                         column(width = 3, align="right",
                                wellPanel(style = "height:300px",
                                          fluidRow(
                                            uiOutput("Opponent"),
                                            uiOutput("opppic")
                                          )))),
                hr(),
                column(offset=5,width = 8,
                       actionBttn("goButton","Start Predictions")),
                hr(),
                column(offset=3,width=6,
                       DTOutput("predictions"))
      )
    )
  )}
...
```

This is my run.R file:

```
library(shiny)

port <- Sys.getenv('PORT')

shiny::runApp(
  appDir = getwd(),
  host = '0.0.0.0',
  port = as.numeric(port)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this [Heroku docker image](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-docker-r). It makes deploying a Shiny app so much easier.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include all the key details in your answer. Right now, if the link breaks or its contents changes your answer will become invalid.